# regex find and replace 0x0D, 0x0A characters

Tags: command-line, text-processing, shell-script

I have a text file of a database dump with some line break characters (`0x0A0x0D`) in the middle of lines. I want to replace them with commas, but I can't do it simply, because those characters are the actual line break characters where I *do* want line breaks!

But I noticed that the line break sequences I want to keep are surrouned by space characters ( `0x20`), so I was thinking a regex to find and replace any `0x0A0x0D` sequence without a leading or trailing space.

How can I do this?

Comment: I'm on android so I can't check this. I believe you can use sed and match \x0a\x0d after each other. In a unix file the line endings you want to keep are lf alone.

Comment: The file originates from windows :P

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The regex for a whitespace character is, of course, `\s`.  However, since you want a non-whitespace character, you can use `\S`!  Therefore, your regex to replace would be `\S\n\r\S`.

EDIT:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict; use warnings;
my $pattern = "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxy\n\ryxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx \n\r xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxy\n\ryxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx";
$pattern =~ s/(\S)(\n\r)(\S)/$1$3/g;
print "$pattern\n";
exit;
```

result:

```
xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxyyxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx 

 xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxyyxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
```

I changed the regex to replace with `$1$3` so you retain the characters that `\S` matches.

Comment: Sorry to be confusing -- `0x0A0x0D` I mean to be the hex notation for the `\r\n` dos-style line breaks. They aren't literal characters.

Comment: I tried `perl -e "s/\S\r\n\S/,/g" -pi.save vIndexes.txt` and it didn't work :P

Comment: Thinking that maybe I was dumb and the perl regex parser understood hex characters, I also tried `perl -e "s/\S0x0A0x0D\S/replaced/g;" -pi.save testfile` and it didn't work either.

Comment: Are you looking for `\r\n` or `\n\r`? Try `perl -e "s/\S\n\r\S/,/g" -pi.save vIndexes.txt` instead?

Answer (score 0):

Here's a way with GNU awk. Set the [record separator](http://www.gnu.org/s/gawk/manual/gawk.html#Records) `RS` to match the separators you want to keep, and weed out the other `\r\n` sequences.

```
gawk -vRS=' \r\n ' '{gsub(/\r\n/, ""); printf "%s%s", $0, RT}'
```